# Error : "you don't have permissions to access that sheet" -> Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import datas from an other sheet where I am not the owner.
The owner gived me permissions but I still have this error :
you don't have permissions to access that sheet

Here is my formula :

```
= importrange(C1, "sheetname!sheetrange")
```

At the cell "C1", there is the url of the file that have the datas that I need.

So I dont know how to solve this error because as I said, I already have the permission on the other file.

Comment: First try importing a single cell so sheets can get connected using the syntax: `=IMPORTRANGE("URL", "sheetname!A1")`

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos , I have the same error with your syntax

Comment: Please share some data and your formula or a test sheet.

Comment: What kind of permissions do you have over the sheet? Are you an editor, commenter, or viewer? I am asking because it seems like you may have access to see the information of the sheet but not enough access to import the data

Comment: @FernandoLara I have the editor permission.
When I am in the sheet i can do everything but I cant import datas from this sheet